# Mutltiple UISplitviewControllers in TabBar are not all notified of rotations events

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an application with a tabBar containing 3 UISplitiViewControllers. Everything works well except for one scenario:

I have the ipad in landscape position on tab1. I click on tab3,  then I rotate the ipad portrait mode. I click on tab1, it is well displayed in portrait mode, I'm happy.

I now come back to landscape position.

I click again on tab3 and there, the splitView controller is still displayed in "portrait mode". the delegate of my splitviewController in tab3 was never called.

Is there a way to force the rotation of this splitViewController in the "viewWillAppear"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep analysis of event bubbling, it appears that rotation events are not forwarded to hidden splitViews... 
There is no way to forward these events without using hidden apis.

Lots a developers have the same problem and this implementation of event management in splitView has been reported as a bug to apple, even though guidelines are to use only one splitView added to the root view of application.

Comment: My class (@zebs mentioned) doesn't rely on hidden api's per se, I do cheat a little bit to quickly get popover buttons, by asking for a _property directly, but if you so chose, you could comment that out and uncomment the bit that walks the view hierarchy to pull the button the long way. The same end result, both undesirably fragile, but both work (for now).  I'll add that not everyone has perfect luck with IntelligentSplitviewController, but it "works for me" quite well. Matt's full on reimplementation is my next stop if my class ever goes belly up or is outlawed by uncle steve-o.

Comment: I have a simpler alternative, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your might find [this](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController) git useful.

It is just a simple subclass of `UISplitViewController` that is notified of rotation changes.

Alternatively, [this](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) is a more robust replacement that adds lots of features.

Hope it helps.

BTW I have gotten apps approved using these classes.